# single sign on between wordpress and opencart

Tags: wordpress, plugins, single-sign-on, opencart, subdomain

i am working on wordpress and opencart. my main domain is running in wordpress for ex example.com and my sub-domain  running  on opencart for ex store.example.com .

now my question is that i want to implement single sign functionality on wordpress website(register user of wordpress website) to my store.example.com( which is built on opencart) means of in subdomains.

if i am approaching to get current user of example.com(which is built on wordpress) into the store.example.com(which is built on opencart) how can i manage that?

or what if i supposed to get current user login information which is recently logged into wordpress site into opencart site while opencart site is loaded how it get done any suggestion to this approach

if is there any plugin available for wordpress to opencart single sign on then feel free to suggest.

any suggestion and answers will be appreciate.